# xsl:for-each Split Records

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, xslt-1.0

I'm not sure if this is even possible but here we go.

I have an xml file:

```
<ROOT>
  <MEM-STMT>   
    <COUNTRY>co</COUNTRY>   
    <CURRENCY>cu</CURRENCY>   
    <STMT>   
      <ST-NO>1</ST-NO>   
      <ST-DATE>21-JUL-11</ST-DATE>   
      <CC>21</CC>   
      <YY>11</YY>   
      <MM>07</MM>   
      <DD>21</DD>   
    </STMT>   
    <MEM-DET>   
      <MEM-NO>9</MEM-NO>   
      <MEM-PROD-LEV>24</MEM-PROD-LEV>   
      <MEM-OPTION>option</MEM-OPTION>   
      <MEM-EMP-NO/>   
      <MEM-EMP-NAME>name</MEM-EMP-NAME>   
    </MEM-DET>   
    <MEM-ADDR>   
      <MEM-NAME>name</MEM-NAME>   
      <MEM-ADDR1>                  Addr1</MEM-ADDR1>   
      <MEM-ADDR2>                           Addr2</MEM-ADDR2>   
      <MEM-ADDR3>                         Addr3</MEM-ADDR3>   
      <MEM-SUB>                            Sub</MEM-SUB>   
      <MEM-CITY>                          +2</MEM-CITY>   
      <MEM-REG>                   Employer:reg</MEM-REG>   
      <MEM-CNTRY/>   
      <MEM-PCODE/>   
      <MEM-EMPCODE/>   
    </MEM-ADDR>   
    <ACC>   
      <PROV>   
        <PR-NO>1</PR-NO>   
        <PR-NAME>  pr</PR-NAME>   
        <REF-NO>1</REF-NO>   
        <CLM>   
          <REF>1</REF>   
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>   
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>   
          <CL-DOS>10-APR-11</CL-DOS>   
          <CC>21</CC>   
          <YY>11</YY>   
          <MM>04</MM>   
          <DD>10</DD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>1 </CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc </CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>   
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>   
          <CL-LINE>2</CL-LINE>   
          <CL-AMT>16.8</CL-AMT>   
          <CL-TAR-AMT>16.8</CL-TAR-AMT>   
          <CL-PAID-PROV>16.8</CL-PAID-PROV>   
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>   
          <CL-RSN/>   
        </CLM>   
        <CLM>   
          <REF>1</REF>   
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>   
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep </CL-DEP-NAME>   
          <CL-DOS>20-APR-11</CL-DOS>   
          <CC>21</CC>   
          <YY>11</YY>   
          <MM>04</MM>   
          <DD>20</DD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>1 </CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc </CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>   
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>   
          <CL-LINE>2</CL-LINE>   
          <CL-AMT>50.4</CL-AMT>   
          <CL-TAR-AMT>50.4</CL-TAR-AMT>   
          <CL-PAID-PROV>50.4</CL-PAID-PROV>   
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>   
          <CL-RSN/>   
        </CLM>   
        <TOTALS>   
          <TOT-AMT>67.2</TOT-AMT>   
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>67.2</TOT-TAR-AMT>   
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>67.2</TOT-PAID-PROV>   
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>   
        </TOTALS>   
      </PROV>   
      <PROV>   
        <PR-NO>2</PR-NO>   
        <PR-NAME>  pr</PR-NAME>   
        <REF-NO>1</REF-NO>   
        <CLM>   
          <REF>1</REF>   
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>   
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>   
          <CL-DOS>10-APR-11</CL-DOS>   
          <CC>21</CC>   
          <YY>11</YY>   
          <MM>04</MM>   
          <DD>10</DD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>1</CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc </CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>   
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>   
          <CL-LINE>2</CL-LINE>   
          <CL-AMT>15</CL-AMT>   
          <CL-TAR-AMT>0</CL-TAR-AMT>   
          <CL-PAID-PROV>15</CL-PAID-PROV>   
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>   
          <CL-RSN/>   
        </CLM>   
        <TOTALS>   
          <TOT-AMT>15</TOT-AMT>   
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>0</TOT-TAR-AMT>   
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>15</TOT-PAID-PROV>   
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>   
        </TOTALS>   
      </PROV>   
      <PROV>   
        <PR-NO>1</PR-NO>   
        <PR-NAME>  pr</PR-NAME>   
        <REF-NO>I0428202</REF-NO>   
        <CLM>   
          <REF>I0428202</REF>   
          <CL-DEP-NO>03</CL-DEP-NO>   
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>   
          <CL-DOS>10-APR-11</CL-DOS>   
          <CC>21</CC>   
          <YY>11</YY>   
          <MM>04</MM>   
          <DD>10</DD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>2</CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc</CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>   
          <CL-NO>112153</CL-NO>   
          <CL-LINE>217615</CL-LINE>   
          <CL-AMT>31.58</CL-AMT>   
          <CL-TAR-AMT>0</CL-TAR-AMT>   
          <CL-PAID-PROV>31.58</CL-PAID-PROV>   
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>   
          <CL-RSN/>   
        </CLM>   
        <TOTALS>   
          <TOT-AMT>31.58</TOT-AMT>   
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>0</TOT-TAR-AMT>   
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>31.58</TOT-PAID-PROV>   
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>   
        </TOTALS>   
      </PROV>   
      <PROV>   
        <PR-NO>1</PR-NO>   
        <PR-NAME> pr</PR-NAME>   
        <REF-NO>0027579</REF-NO>   
        <CLM>   
          <REF>1</REF>   
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>   
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>   
          <CL-DOS>09-JUN-11</CL-DOS>   
          <CC>21</CC>   
          <YY>11</YY>   
          <MM>06</MM>   
          <DD>09</DD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>99200 </CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>   
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc</CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>   
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>   
          <CL-LINE>1</CL-LINE>   
          <CL-AMT>12</CL-AMT>   
          <CL-TAR-AMT>0</CL-TAR-AMT>   
          <CL-PAID-PROV>12</CL-PAID-PROV>   
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>   
          <CL-RSN/>   
        </CLM>   
        <TOTALS>   
          <TOT-AMT>12</TOT-AMT>   
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>0</TOT-TAR-AMT>   
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>12</TOT-PAID-PROV>   
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>   
        </TOTALS>   
      </PROV>   
    </ACC>   
    <RSN-LIST>   
      <RSN-ERR>????</RSN-ERR>   
      <RSN-DESC/>   
    </RSN-LIST>   
    <FIN-OTHER>   
      <FIN-DATE/>   
      <FIN-AMT>0</FIN-AMT>   
      <FIN-TT/>   
    </FIN-OTHER>   
    <GTOTALS>   
      <GTOT-AMT>125.78</GTOT-AMT>   
      <GTOT-TAR-AMT>67.2</GTOT-TAR-AMT>   
      <GTOT-PAID-PROV>125.78</GTOT-PAID-PROV>   
      <GTOT-PAID-MEM>0</GTOT-PAID-MEM>   
    </GTOTALS>   
    <MEM-GTOT>   
      <M-MESSAGE/>   
      <M-TOT-PAID-MEM>0</M-TOT-PAID-MEM>   
      <M-PMT-METH/>   
    </MEM-GTOT>   
    <FIN-BAL>   
      <FIN-BDATE>21-JUL-11</FIN-BDATE>   
      <FIN-BAMT>0</FIN-BAMT>   
      <FIN-BTT/>   
    </FIN-BAL>   
  </MEM-STMT>   
</ROOT>
```

& I'd like to split the records returned from it using the logic below:

If the xml file has 30 or more PROV-or-CLM-or-TOTATALS nodes then process only 30 PROV-or-CLM-or-TOTATALS nodes. Do this for the entire xml file in case where the number of remaining nodes is less than 30 process them to complete the transformation.

I'm using the following xsl to do this:

```
<xsl:template name="PROVIDER">
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="global">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<fo:wrapper font-size="7pt" font-family="Helvetica">
<fo:block-container >
<xsl:variable name="CURRENCYSYMBOL"><xsl:value-of select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/CURRENCY"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/ACC/PROV">
<xsl:if test="(position() mod 30 = 1)">
<fo:block >
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="190mm" border-style="solid">
    <fo:table-column column-width="22mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="16mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="18mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="39mm"/>
<!--    <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>  -->
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>

    <fo:table-header border="solid" >
        <fo:table-row  border-style="solid">
        <fo:table-cell  background-color="{$HeaderGray}" number-columns-spanned="9" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block font-size="7pt" text-align="left" font-weight="bold">Provider:
            <xsl:value-of select="PR-NO"/>-
            <xsl:value-of select="PR-NAME"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA0;  </xsl:text>  Ref No:
            <xsl:value-of select="REF-NO"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>

        <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Patient</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Serv Date</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Tariff/Drug</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Description</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    <!--    <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Claim No</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>     -->
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Claim Amount</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Tariff Amount</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Paid Provider</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Paid Member</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Reason</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>

<xsl:for-each select="./CLM">
    <xsl:if test="(position() mod 30 = 1)"> 
    <fo:table-body font-size="7pt">
    <fo:table-row>

        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
            <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-DEP-NAME"/><xsl:text>&#xA0;  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-DEP-NO"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
            <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-DOS"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
            <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-TAR-DRUG-CD"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>

        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
            <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    <!--    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-NO"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>  -->
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
            <xsl:if test="CL-AMT != '0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(CL-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
            <xsl:if test="CL-TAR-AMT != '0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(CL-TAR-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
            <fo:block text-align="right">
            <xsl:if test="CL-PAID-PROV != '0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(CL-PAID-PROV,'#,##0.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
            <xsl:if test="CL-PAID-MEM != '0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(CL-PAID-MEM,'#,##0.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
                <xsl:if test="CL-RSN != '????'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="CL-RSN"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>

    </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="./TOTALS">
    <xsl:if test="(position() mod 30 = 1)">
    <fo:table-body font-size="7pt">

    <fo:table-row border-style="solid">

        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" number-columns-spanned="4" >
            <fo:block >Totals for Invoice</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>

        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
            <fo:block text-align="right">
        <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-AMT != '0'">       -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TOT-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
        <!--    </xsl:if>     -->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell >
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
        <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-TAR-AMT != '0'">  -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TOT-TAR-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
        <!--    </xsl:if>    -->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
        <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-PAID-PROV != '0'">    -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TOT-PAID-PROV,'#,##0.00')"/>
        <!--    </xsl:if>    -->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:block text-align="right">
        <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-PAID-MEM != '0'">   -->
                <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(TOT-PAID-MEM,'#,##0.00')"/>
        <!--    </xsl:if>   -->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell >
            <fo:block>

            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table>
</fo:block>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</fo:block-container>
</fo:wrapper>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

My current scenario is such that the split doesn't work & I get the exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space despite allocating  -Xms/-Xmx2G memory.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear. You are talking about taking the first 30 items, but you are using the modulo operator in your code. It looks like you are trying to put every 30 items (1-30, 31-60, 61-..) in a table. Is that correct? Is so, you will need a nested loop.

Comment: Also, can PROV, CLM and TOTALS occur in mixed order? Should these be displaying in separate tables? First all those of PROV, then the others?

Comment: @grtjn this is 100% what I'm trying to do - "put every 30 items (1-30, 31-60, 61-..)". About a nested loop, CLM & TOTALS are subnodes of PROV - CLM occurs first & then TOTALS (also CLM & TOTALS can occur multiple times within one PROV node). To evaluate them each I have to go through PROV first - That's how I'm using a nested loop, I'm not sure if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kamza, you had part of it right, but there are a few flaws in your approach. You start with a for-each on PROV elements, and within the for-each you have an if that causes output to be written only for PROV elements 1, 31, 61, etc. The nested for-each loops have a similar problem. Only CLM element 1, 31, 61, .. is written, like only TOTALS 1, 31, 61, ..

(Actually, I suspect there will only be one TOTALS within each PROV, so that would ok in your code.)

Furthermore, from what I understand from your description and the comments is that you are trying to write out 30 rows at a time, and start a new table, or even a new page after that, with another 30 rows, or what is left. Since no rows are written for the PROV element itself, I presume that it is just about CLM and TOTALS rows, where the count of 30 should include both.

What you need for that is an outer for-each loop that walks along all CLM and TOTALS elements. You can use this expression for that:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/ACC/PROV/*[self::CLM or self::TOTALS]">
```

Then use the if you already have to create a new table for row 1, 31, 61, ...

To fill the table with the first-next 30 items, you will need to look forward 30 positions. The PROV element is a bit of a problem here. Assuming CLM and TOTALS only occur within PROV, and PROV is not used elsewhere, you can reasonably safely use the following axis for that:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="(following::*[self::CLM or self::TOTALS])[30 >= position()]">
```

That returns 30 items, both CLM and TOTALS mixed, but in document order. You need two extra if's (or a choose) to distinguish between these two, and output the appropriate table row:

```
    <xsl:if test="self::CLM">
        ...
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="self::TOTALS">
        ...
    </xsl:if>
```

In your code you have fo:table-body within the inner for-each loops, causing each table-row to be wrapped in a new table-body. That is unnecessary. Move the table-body to outside the inner loops. You would need only one wrapping both rows of CLM and TOTALS.

Finally, you write a new table for each 30th item. I think you want to start a new page-sequence as well. That will cause each table to be shown on a separate page. Putting things together, you get an XSLT similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:variable name="HeaderGray" select="'gray'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="global">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="PROVIDER"/>

        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="PROVIDER">
        <xsl:variable name="CURRENCYSYMBOL" select="string(ROOT/MEM-STMT/CURRENCY)"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/ACC/PROV/*[self::CLM or self::TOTALS]">
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 30 = 1">

                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="global">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <fo:wrapper font-size="7pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                            <fo:block-container>
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="190mm"
                                        border-style="solid">
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="22mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="16mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="18mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="39mm"/>
                                        <!--    <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>  -->
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>

                                        <fo:table-header border="solid">
                                            <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="{$HeaderGray}"
                                                  number-columns-spanned="9" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block font-size="7pt" text-align="left"
                                                  font-weight="bold">Provider: <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="PR-NO"/>- <xsl:value-of select="PR-NAME"/>
                                                  <xsl:text>&#xA0;  </xsl:text> Ref No:
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="REF-NO"/>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>

                                            <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Patient</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Serv Date</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Tariff/Drug</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Description</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <!--    <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt"> 
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold">Claim No</fo:block> 
        </fo:table-cell>     -->
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Claim Amount</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Tariff Amount</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Paid Provider</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Paid Member</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold"
                                                  >Reason</fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                        </fo:table-header>

                                        <fo:table-body font-size="7pt">
                                            <xsl:for-each
                                            select="(following::*[self::CLM or self::TOTALS])[30 >= position()]">
                                            <xsl:if test="self::CLM">
                                                  <fo:table-row>

                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block>
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="CL-DEP-NAME"/>
                                                  <xsl:text>&#xA0;  </xsl:text>
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="CL-DEP-NO"/>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block>
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="CL-DOS"/>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block>
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="CL-TAR-DRUG-CD"/>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>

                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block>
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC"/>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <!--    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"> 
            <fo:block> 
            <xsl:value-of select="CL-NO"/> 
            </fo:block> 
        </fo:table-cell>  -->
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <xsl:if test="CL-AMT != '0'">
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(CL-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  </xsl:if>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <xsl:if test="CL-TAR-AMT != '0'">
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(CL-TAR-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  </xsl:if>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <xsl:if test="CL-PAID-PROV != '0'">
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(CL-PAID-PROV,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  </xsl:if>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <xsl:if test="CL-PAID-MEM != '0'">
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(CL-PAID-MEM,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  </xsl:if>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <xsl:if test="CL-RSN != '????'">
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="CL-RSN"/>
                                                  </xsl:if>
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>

                                                  </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="self::TOTALS">

                                                  <fo:table-row border-style="solid">

                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"
                                                  number-columns-spanned="4">
                                                  <fo:block>Totals for Invoice</fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>

                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-AMT != '0'">       -->
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(TOT-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  <!--    </xsl:if>     -->
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-TAR-AMT != '0'">  -->
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(TOT-TAR-AMT,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  <!--    </xsl:if>    -->
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-PAID-PROV != '0'">    -->
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(TOT-PAID-PROV,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  <!--    </xsl:if>    -->
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                                                  <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                  <!--    <xsl:if test="TOT-PAID-MEM != '0'">   -->
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="$CURRENCYSYMBOL"/>
                                                  <xsl:value-of
                                                  select="format-number(TOT-PAID-MEM,'#,##0.00')"/>
                                                  <!--    </xsl:if>   -->
                                                  </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:table-cell>
                                                  <fo:block> </fo:block>
                                                  </fo:table-cell>
                                                  </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        </fo:table-body>
                                    </fo:table>
                                </fo:block>

                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:wrapper>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I am not entirely convinced this will prevent you from getting an exception. You gave the impression it is because of your for-each loops, but it may be caused by something else. A table that is simply to big, or an fo document that is too large to render might be the cause as well, for instance. The above code should be fairly efficient. If it is still giving you trouble, try processing things from the command-line, perhaps even using different parsers.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much - you an absolute genius!! I've learnt so much from your posts - much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

hm.. I don't have time to look at your xslt in detail, but your logic should be possible using something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="(//PROV | //CLM | //TOTALS)[position() <= 30]">
   <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'PROV'">
       <!-- do stuff with PROV node -->
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'CLM'">
       <!-- do stuff with CLM node -->
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'TOTALS'">
       <!-- do stuff with TOTALS node -->
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll implement your suggestion & let you know how it goes..

Comment: When I run my code I get errors: "A node test that matches either NCName:* or QName was expected." & "Extra illegal tokens: ')', '[', 'position', '(', ')', '<', '30', ']'
" on line <xsl:template match="(//PROV | //CLM | //TOTALS)[position() <= 30]">. How should I call this template from the main template? I'm using <xsl:apply-templates select="(//PROV | //CLM | //TOTALS)[position() &lt; 30]">.

Comment: @kamza A template match cannot be written like that, but you could replace <xsl:template match= with <xsl:for-each select=, and use that to replace the outlines of your own for-each loops..

Comment: @grtjn thanks for the clarification. I made the changes, now I'm getting (Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Error(Unknown location): fo:block-container is missing child elements. Required Content Model: marker* (%block;)+. I'm guessing that it's because all the if-statements (or just the first one: <xsl:if test="name() = PROV">) are evaluating to false.

Comment: @kamza I altered the code above to replace '==' (doesn't exist in xslt) by '=', and quoted the right operands. Make sure the element names are quoted, otherwise it thinks you want to compare the local-name() with the *value* of a child element named PROV.

Comment: @kamza Actually, there is a nicer way of doing the tests: "self::PROV", or if you are using XSLT 2.0: "exists(self::PROV)". (So, no local-name, no equals operator, just that..)

Comment: @grtjn thanks for the tips - the 2nd one particularly is very neat - (+2) for that... However my question is still not full answered. Instead of processing 30 records at a time I'm only processing 30 & then exiting. How should I change if-statement condition to make provision for this? How can I add comments vote?

Comment: @kamza Moving the discussion to your question. (Vote comments? Earn more reputation I expect? :)

Comment: @grtjn you made two good comments I wanted to up vote (I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology for this site) them.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your xsl:for-each statements, to restrict them to the first 30 items:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/ACC/PROV[position()&lt;=30]">
```

Or you could extract the `xsl:for-each` logic out into templates and then select only the first 30 to apply templates to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/ACC/PROV[position()&lt;=30]"/>
```

Comment: I implemented the 1st suggestion but I still run out of memory. I'm not sure how to implement the 2nd suggestion though. What should I name template that's called with the line <xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT/MEM-STMT/ACC/PROV[position()&lt;=30]"/>? As you might have guessed, I'm quite a novice when it comes to xslt/xsl-fo.